# In Microsoft Word, how can I prevent a find what command from being searched when mentioned in the document?

Tags: microsoft-word, search, microsoft-word-2007

I am using the Find what section of Microsoft Word (I'm using version 2007) to find file paths, which begin with a double quote and end with a double quote followed by the paragraph mark. I am using the wildcard character (*) to do this search, along with the escape character of . To help myself remember the specific command to use in the future, I typed it in the document.

However, as you can see from the picture, Word is finding the exact search command and stopping when it sees the first occurrence of a double quote followed by a paragraph mark. I am not sure why it doesn't ignore the mention of the search because to me if I wanted to find double backslashes I should have to enter three backslashes the way I have to enter two now to find one.

So, what is the correct search term needed to get the mention of the search term ignored and only the file paths with the paragraph mark found?

Here is a picture that best illustrates what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: paraphrase your notes, or put extra spaces between things, just so it won't match.  (or both!).  **S** **P** **A** **C** **E** **S** or **D-A-S-H-E-S** can be used effectively too.

Answer (score 1):

Your `*` also matches the second `\`, to prevent it use:

`"C:\\[!\\]*"^13`

### update

I've realized `\` has to be skipped also in `[]`, also added more criteria according to your description to avoid matching multiple row long entries:

`"C:\\[!\\][!"^13]@"^13`

- `[!\\]` to avoid matching second `\` in your text
- `[!"^13]@` to avoid continuing search in multiple rows when path doesn't end in `"^13`

Comment: I can't get this syntax to work. I also typed it out in case something went wrong or the double quotes were of a different kind, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Rolo please see my updates